# how to cast a domain to a Collection Set in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

```
def tags = tipLists.collect{it.tags}
render(template:'listTags',model:[tagList:tags])
```

`tags` are the set(Collection). I need to cast `TipTag` (domain class) to the Collection Set `tags` and forward it to a template gsp `listTags`

How to do this? any possibility??

Comment: Can you complement your question with more structure? What's the content of TipTag? Tags is a Set of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Have Done this,

```
 List<TipTag> tagsList = tipLists.collect{it.tags}
    render(template:'listTags',model:[tagList:tags])
```

This Worked out for me  !